# Can multiple gearman servers share the same libdrizzle queue?

Tags: high-availability, gearman, job-queue, libdrizzle

Can multiple gearman *servers* share the same gearman queue, via libdrizzle?

I'm wondering if this will eliminate the gearman server as a single point of failure--if I have multiple web nodes, each talking to the same gearman server, then the site dies if gearman becomes unavailable.  However, if each of the web nodes is running its own gearman server (and jobs generated by that node are queued to the gearman server running on the same node), then the single point of failure is moved to the database.  (Which, in our architecture, is a single point of failure anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The queue is only used as a backup in case the in memory queue fails (if Gearman dies, the jobs will still be stored in the database). The persistent queue is only read at startup, and not during job processing.

This doesn't mean that you can't have two Gearman servers and add both the servers to your clients and workers (so that the workers register with both servers) and have redundancy that way. I can't say that I've had a gearman server die on me recently anyways, but you'll at least get an extra level of failsafe.